# Performing an operation on a variable and and assigning it to the same variable

Tags: performance, matlab, variables

I commonly perform an operation on a variable, and then assign the outcome from that operation to the variable. Just a few such examples:

```
A = [A; -A];
B = B.';  %'
bigArray = bigArray(:,:,1:8,9);
distMatrix = sqrt(sum(distMatrix.*distMatrix,3));
```

Is it faster/more efficient/better coding practice to avoid such use and assign the answer to a new variable, such  as:

```
myNewArray = sum([elephant(operation(myArray),8); -myArray.'],3);
```

It seems to me that it should be considered better coding practice, but from a purely speed and memory viewpoint, which is better?

Thanks.

Comment: On a related note, Matlab offers a profiler. So, if you're ever wondering about performance, you can always run the profiler against both implementations and check the difference.  [Profiler Help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)

Comment: @JeremyMangas Thanks, I thought about using the profiler, but I didn't quite have a fully implemented code to spam at that stage!

Comment: Also seems like the code-prettyfier doesn't recognise MATLAB's `.'` operator, but thinks I haven't closed my quotes!

Comment: Well done for using `.'` and not `'`

Comment: You should congratulate my teachers; I didn't know that you could transpose with only `'`.

Comment: @Lui Well, there is no code-prettyfier for Matlab - so have a look at my edit, thats how we usually go around this issue.

Comment: @thewaywewalk That works pretty well, although it does make it look like the `%` is part of the code as it's now a different colour, so I don't really like it... Also with your edit I had MATLAB in the title because it would be different for different languages, and also I think it's a good idea to use the same verb style consistently in the title.

Comment: @Lui About the title: Putting Matlab in the title is obsolete and usually edited out by everybody, as it does not add any information. The language you use is specified by the tag. About the `%'` Surely a matter of taste, it's certainly not code, but a comment - and wouldn't you rather have a meaningless comment, than subsequent code, which is highlighted as a string. You can always re-edit your own posts or rollback the previous state, if you don't support the previous edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of speed and performance, there will be little noticeable overhead assigning to a new variable compared to the calculations you're performing. Technically speaking, reusing the existing variable avoids creating a new reference required for the new variable. If you're using a 64 bit OS this will be 8 bytes of memory.

The only time the performance of this allocation could possibly be noticed would be if you're constantly assigning to a new variable inside a loop. Even then, the reference will be on the stack so it will still be negligible.